# You cannot use '!=' filters more than once

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to use `isNotEqualt` filter for two different values in StreamBuilder's where() function, but when I do this using two different where() functions as in the code I gave, ***"You cannot use '!=' filters more than once."*** I've tried combining the two in many ways, but either I'm getting an error or the filter isn't working.

```
StreamBuilder < QuerySnapshot > (
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('folders').where('docId', isNotEqualTo: docId).where('folderPath', isNotEqualTo: docId).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot < QuerySnapshot > snapshot) {}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behavior, The [Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) says

> Only a single not-in or !=` is allowed per query.

Comment: And not that `not-in` takes up to 10 values so here you have your `!=` on several values